# getting subquery error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, mysql-dependent-subquery

Trying to insert into some table using my current table . Here is the structure of my current Temptable:

```
CustomerID  Name        Values      FakeName
1           John        10apples    10apples_20oranges_30bananas
1           John        20oranges   10apples_20oranges_30bananas
1           John        30bananas   10apples_20oranges_30bananas
2           Steve       15apples    15apples_25oranges_35bananas
2           Steve       25oranges   15apples_25oranges_35bananas
2           Steve       35bananas   15apples_25oranges_35bananas
3           Harvey      10apples    10apples_20oranges_30bananas
3           Harvey      20oranges   10apples_20oranges_30bananas
3           Harvey      30bananas   10apples_20oranges_30bananas
```

This is my peice of code that I am executing :

```
Insert into customer (FakeName,type,address)
select (select distinct FakeName from Temptable),
        2,
        xyz

 from customer c
 where c.fakename not in (select distinct Fakename from TempTable)
```

getting following `error`

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

I want to insert distinct Fakenames from `temptable` to `customer` table , making sure if the fake name already exist then not to insert a duplicate fakename

Comment: Why are you selecting from the subquery instead of just selecting `c.fakename` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select distinct FakeName from Temptable` is not a scalar, so you can't use it like that.

I think this is what you're after:

```
Insert into customer (FakeName,type,address)
select distinct 
        FakeName,
        2,
        xyz
 from Temptable c
 where c.fakename not in (select distinct Fakename from customer)
```

Comment: I tried this but it is inserting duplicates. Like when i do " select * from customer where FakeName in '10apples_20oranges_30bananas' " , it is giving me 3 outputs with the same FakeName. My expectation is to see only 1

Comment: Distinct removes duplicates. By 'duplicate' do you mean the same FakeName appears twice? that's because column `xyz` has a different value. You need to pick which xyz you want.

Comment: Just run this: `select distinct FakeName from Temptable` Do you see duplicates?

Comment: How about this: `select distinct LTRIM(RTRIM(FakeName) from Temptable` Can you post a screenshot of the duplicates if you still see them

Comment: I mean `select distinct LTRIM(RTRIM(FakeName)) from Temptable` (forgot a bracket)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
Insert into customer (FakeName, type, address)
    select distinct tt.FakeName, 2, 'xyz'
    from temptable tt
    where not exists (select 1 from customer c where c.fakename = tt.fakename);
```

Notes:

- `xyz` is undefined in your query (unless it is a column in customer, which seems unlikely).
- `not in` will filter all rows if any name the subquery is `NULL`.  I replaced it with `not exists`.
- I am speculating that you want to avoid duplicate entries in `customer`, so I changed the subquery.
- When using `in`/`not in` with a subquery, `select distinct` is redundant.

Comment: I tried this but it is inserting duplicates. Like when i do " select * from customer where FakeName in '10apples_20oranges_30bananas' " , it is giving me 6 outputs with the same FakeName. My expectation is to see only 1

Comment: @achillies1987 . . . Perhaps the duplicates look the same, but different by having spaces, hidden characters, or characters that look the same.